# Can't get a JS var inserted into a hidden field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, hidden

I promise...I have researched this for over 24 hours.  I know it is similar (if not exactly the same) as some other questions.  I'm obviously missing something.  (This is going to be a long-winded explanation...I apologize.  Please don't let it scare you off...I'm pretty sure the root problem/question will be much easier than what all this looks like!)

End result desired is to get some JS vars POSTed over to my process PHP script from an HTML form.  Simple, right?

I have a fully working form that does a bunch of calculations with a *bunch* of input fields...it's way too complex to post here...not to mention I really don't want to embarrass myself with what I'm sure is very bad coding!

In a nutshell...I have a function that in the process of running sets various JS vars.  I need to get these vars inserted into some hidden input fields so that they will get moved over to my processing PHP along with all of the "normal" inputs.  All of these vars represent floating point numbers (if that makes any diff)

Here is my form definition:

```
<form id="multiForm" action="App_post.php" method="POST" action="javascript:void(0)" id="appform" name="appform">
```

I have a "master" function that starts all of the calculations primarily based on when the user selects various radio buttons.  Various selectors are dynamically updated in the form as the user selects buttons (which in reality is a user selecting different options of club membership fees and "add-on" items...someone is bound to ask what I'm doing!)

```
$(function () {
...lots of JS code here along with the calculations that create the JS vars I need
}
```

(I assume this function is called via the action="javascript:void(0)" )

Let's focus on just one var right now.  The JS var "regularfee" (along with all the others I want) exists after all of the calculations are done.  I need to have these values plugged into the hidden fields so that they can get POSTed.

Here is an example of the hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="regularfee" id="regularfee" value="">
```

Here is where I am getting lost.  I have done a console.log(regularfee) in the function right after all the calculations are done...it is set to the float number 26.5 (which is correct)

Here are a couple of things I have tried so far:

```
document.getElementById('regularfee').value=regularfee;
//  --OR--
document.getElementById('regularfee').value=regularfee.value;
document.getElementById("app").submit();
```

No matter what I've tried, I get blank values POSTED over to my process PHP.  Based on the other questions I've seen, the hidden input field method *appears* to be one of the "accepted" ways of doing this.  I am not stuck on this method...just looking for the easiest way to get my vars POSTed! What am I missing?  All help extremely appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors on the console?

Comment: if you open the console, and enter document.getElementById('regularfee') what does it print?

Comment: @Jack - No JS errors...as I said the form is "working" just fine in it's present mode.  Problem is only trying to get the vars "out"

Comment: @nycynik - console.log shows the proper value of regularfee to be  26.5 at a point right after all calcs are done

Comment: @nycynik - sorry...just read your question closer...I was originally just checking regularfee in console.  document.getElementById('regularfee') shows null

Answer (score 0):

Try regular post or use AJAX to SUbmit.

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

This method gets all input in ur form including select and checked.

```
  //multiForm form is your ID in ur form
 var data = $("#multiForm :input").serializeObject();
```

after use ajax to save in php script.

```
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "phpscript.php",
        data: data,
    success: function() {
         alert("Input Success!");
         }
        });
```

How this will help you!

Comment: Pardon my ignorance...but I'm trying to follow your answer.  I don't see where it deals at all with the JS var "regularfee" (a floating point number).  Again...probably just my ignorance but this *seems* to do something else.

Comment: PLease put your html code for us to follow what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this syntax should be good to go...

```
document.getElementById('regularfee').value=regularfee;
```

This is assuming that the regularfee variable exists and it is of type float. Or even better use jQuery

```
$('#regularfee').val([your value here]);
```

Question, why do you have two actions in your form? How does it work?

```
<form id="multiForm" action="App_post.php" method="POST" action="javascript:void(0)" id="appform" name="appform">
```

Also, for peace of mind, also do a console.log to check the value of the hidden field after it's been set

Comment: I have 2 actions because I don't know what I'm doing!! LOL  based on suggestion from user3075664 I am removing that second action.  (So much of what I've done so far is directly related to plagiarizing snippets and examples found on the Internet and a LOT of questions reviewed here on SO!  I had not caught that prior to this.)

Comment: Stupid question - what is the syntax of checking the hidden field val in console?  Never done that!

Comment: console.log(document.getElementById('regularfee').value);

Comment: console result is "undefined"

Comment: That means the element doesn't exist

Comment: I understand that logic...but help me understand the syntax.  I know that when I refer to just plain "regularfee" that this is the JS var...right?  The item that is coming up as undefined...what exactly are we asking for here?  Isn't that one of the HTML form elements?

Comment: Doesn't the fact that I am getting "[regularfee] =>" with print_r($_POST); in my process PHP script mean that it *is* defined?

Answer (score 0):

You have two action attributes in your form.  Remove the second one for "javascript:void(0)".  It is not calling the function you think it is (the anonymous function you have there looks to be executed on dom ready).

Comment: I have no problem in removing this, but is it "contributing" to my problem or just plain not needed?

Comment: Not needed.  Q: when does the variable `regularfee` get set?

Comment: regularfee (along with about 10 other vars that I need to POST) are set near the end of the main function call.  I have attempted all that you see *after* that point in the function so I know all the vars are set with the values I need (and they are definitely floating point)

Comment: ok.  when you submit, look at the "Net" tab of the dev tools.  If you examine the request to app_post.php, do you see the form values set?

Comment: I'm actually doing a print_r($_POST); in my process PHP file to help in troubleshooting.  I see ALL of my fields...hidden and non-hidden but all the hidden are blank

Comment: hmm, out of curiousity, what happens if you submit the form like this?  setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("app").submit(); }, 20);

Comment: Do you mean at the point where I have: document.getElementById("app").submit();  ??  replace your line where my original is?

Comment: Substituting that for my original line "breaks" my form...it no longer performs the calculations when clicking the selection radio buttons

Comment: Not sure why that would be.  See any errors in the error console?  Also, what do you mean by clicking "selection radio buttons"?  You click radio buttons, which obviously changes values in a form field(s).  But what is triggering you calculations?  Onclick handler with the radio buttons?  Then what triggers the form submission?